# PowerShell cmd to copy and paste all subdirectories and their contents?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ms-office

How do I edit this code to copy all subdirectories and their contents and then paste it to the remote workstation?

Purpose of this code is the remote uninstallation of MS Office 2007. I'm using the same code for installation of a newer version.

```
$Computers = (Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=X,DC=Y,DC=Z").Name
ForEach ($Computer in $Computers)
{
Write-Host "Working on $Computer" -ForegroundColor White
Write-Host "Testing access to $Computer" -ForegroundColor White
$HostUp = Test-Connection -ComputerName $Computer -BufferSize 12 -Count 1
If (!($HostUp))
{
Write-Warning -Message "Remote Host is not accessible!" }
Else
{
Write-Host "Success!" -ForegroundColor Green
$items = Get-Item -Path C:\Transfer2007\*
Write-Host "Creating Transfer folder on $Computer" -ForegroundColor Yellow
New-Item -Path \\$computer\c$\Transfer2007 -ItemType Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
foreach ($item in $items)
{
Write-Host "Copying $Item over to $Computer\c$\Transfer2007\" -ForegroundColor Yellow
Copy-Item -Path $item -Destination \\$Computer\C$\Transfer2007\ -Force
}
Write-Host "Starting setup on $Computer" -ForegroundColor White
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { set-location "C:\Transfer2007\"; .\SETUP.exe /uninstall ProPlus /config \UninstallConfig.xml } -ComputerName $Computer -AsJob
}
}
Get-Job | Format-Table
pause
```

With this code, only the content of 'Transfer2007' directory is pasted into the remote workstation. I need to paste all the subdirectories and their contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try 
`Get-Item -Recursive`

and also look at `powershell workflow`
it allows you to install 32 session at once

Answer (score 0):

`Copy-Item` needs to have the `-Recurse` parameter added, so your `Copy-Item` line should be:

```
Copy-Item -Path $item -Destination \\$Computer\C$\Transfer2007\ -Recurse -Force
```